# Green screen when using mobile VLC to play rtsp streaming on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, vlc

I have a player on iOS based on VLC via mobileVLCKit.framework.

When executing and playing a h264 rtsp stream, iPhone will show the video correctly. However, in the beginning few seconds, there is GREEN SCREEN shown. I think the reason is that I-Frame has not arrived, and yuv=000 is mapped to green color in rgb.

Could I add some option or operation that force player to play after receiving I-Frame? Or is there some other method to avoid green screen problem?

Here is my Code

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.player =  [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] init];
        self.player.delegate = self;
        self.player.media = [VLCMedia mediaWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://...."]];
        self.player.drawable = self.contentView;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)play
{
     if (self.player && !self.player.isPlaying) {
         [slef.player play];
     }
}
```

Any reply would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you got any solution. Because i am unable to play the the rtsp urls

Comment: I can play the rtsp url. My problem is the green screen. The final resolution for this problem is skipping the non-key frame in the beginning of playing. It works fine.

Comment: @chih-chunchan how did you solve that exactly? thanks!

Comment: @DevranCosmoUenal : I posted my resolution as an answer for your reference. Hope it can help for you :)

Comment: Hi all, just for reference, I can confirm this issue also for the normal x86-64 PC version of VLC in conjunction with the **OpenGL for Embedded Systems 2** video output setting. The computers were running **Kubuntu 20.04 LTS**, a Linux distro. Interestingly not all h264 video files were affected. However, the solution or workaround was simply to switch back to the normal regular OpenGL video output. After that, every video started to work again. I mention this here because this stackoverflow question has a high ranking. So it may help also normal PC users who have this "green screen" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the modification should be in the function `static picture_t *DecodeVideo( decoder_t *p_dec, block_t **pp_block )` of `/modules/codec/avcodec/video.c`.

Add following code in the beginning of `DecodeVideo()` function to skip non-I frame so that the green screen problem can be solved.

```
if (p_sys->b_first_frame && b_gotpicture) {
    if (AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I != frame->pict_type) {
        av_frame_unref(frame);
        break;
    }
}
```

And then, build mobileVLCKit.framework myself.

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you! :)